# BASH SCRIPT : Code works from terminal but not from rc.local

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ping

I've written a small script that ping's an address and then mounts the device at that address if the ping returned successful. The file is located in rc.local on a Ubuntu Linux System.

It works great if run from a terminal (as root), but won't run from rc.local at boot. I know it's being executed because /tmp/buffalo_mount.log contains "Executing Network Device Detect Script From rc.local". Anyone got any ideas?

NOTE: **Now working!** Please read notes below :-)

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

ADDRESS=192.168.1.101
DATETIME="$(date)"
LOGFILE="/tmp/buffalo_mount.log"

sleep 30s

echo "Executing Network Device Detect Script From rc.local" >> $LOGFILE
    if /bin/ping -c 1 -t 1 $ADDRESS > /tmp/ping 2>&1 ;then  # check the exit code
        echo "$ADDRESS is LIVE  "+$DATETIME >> $LOGFILE # display the output
    # Ping reply was good, so run the mount command.
    echo "Slept, now mounting device" >> $LOGFILE
    /bin/mount /media/Buffalo/Acer-laptop-back_in_time
    else
        echo "$ADDRESS is DEAD  "+$DATETIME >> $LOGFILE
fi
```

Then I had to edit the '/etc/fstab' file so the fstab knows about the mount, but doesn't mount until told to by my script above, using the '**noauto**' parameter. My example in fstab is:-

```
//192.168.1.101/back-in-time/ /media/Buffalo/Acer-laptop-back_in_time cifs **noauto**,guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode,_netdev  0  0
```

Really hope this help someone because it was driving me nuts. Thanks to all those that helped.

Comment: Does the script run before the network is up?

Comment: afaik rc.local *should* run after all other init scripts, and thus also after the network is up. Nevertheless: do you get the $ADRESS is DEAD message in your log?

Comment: No. I only get the "Executing Network Device Detect Script From rc.local" message. Although the LIVE/DEAD message works from root terminal.

Comment: Any your correct, rc.local should be the last script list to run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The -e argument asks sh to exit if a command have a non 0 exist status, thus the script will stop instead of executing the else branch of your if.  You should replace

```
/bin/ping -c 1 -t 1 $ADDRESS > /dev/null 2> /dev/null  # ping and discard output
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
```

by

```
if /bin/ping -c 1 -t 1 $ADDRESS > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the result is the same, besides, my code above works perfectly from a terminal, just not from rc.local. My code detects and reports if the ping was good or bad with no problem at all. There's something wierd about rc.local execution.

Comment: How do you run the script at the command line?  It it is with ., this will not run a new shell and thus not take the -e option into account.  And I forgot to mention that the ping command before the if has to be removed (or it will continue to stop the execution when it fails, preventing the reach the if).

Comment: OK 'AProgrammer', I've used your code and now the buffalo_mount.log is showing that the Ping has been executed (many thanks), but I get the '192.168.1.101 is DEAD' line returned. If I run 'sudo sh /etc/rc.local' command it works with '192.168.1.101 is LIVE' being return in the log and the drive mounting. Since rc.local if pretty mush the last thing to run, what gives?? Thanks guys for your help and patience, but it's very frustrating.

Comment: Log the output of ping instead of sending it to /dev/null, it should give you an hint about what is going wrong.

Comment: Got 'Network Unavailable'. I added a 'sleep 30s' near the top of the script (not the best method, really need to add lines to detect that network card is up). It now detects the ping correctly (guess network was still coming up). Failing to mount the drive though. Tried adding a sleep 120s before the drive mount, but still not mounting. I've edited the code above to show the current file.

Comment: Got it working! rc.local is being a pig about the mount command. So, what I needed to do was put the mount in the '/etc/fstab' file, but with the 'noauto' command, so that fstab knows about the mount, but doesn't mount it until told to by the rc.local script. The fstab line in question = '//192.168.1.101/back-in-time/ /media/Buffalo/Acer-laptop-back_in_time cifs noauto,guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode,_netdev  0  0'  Have changed the script at top to the new mount command.